# Printing cells that correspond to largest values in original data set

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I first found a cycle in a manufacturing process. I collected the 2 largest pressure values from the given cycles and printed them to a new sheet. I now need to capture the corresponding time to where the largest values land. This portion of my code looks like this:

```
df2 = df.groupby('group')['Pressure'].nlargest(2).rename_axis (index=['group','row_index'])
df2 = df.groupby('group')['Date/Time']
```

A sample snippet of the data I am trying to extract can be seen here:

[image: Date/Time with corresponding pressure]

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the data frame and take the last 2 rows per group. Typing this in the blind as you did not provide sample data:

```py
df2 = (
    df.sort_values(['group', 'Pressure'])
      .groupby('group', sort=False)
      .tail(2)
)
```